# Wordpress page edit stops working after wordpress update

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7

The website I'm working on uses WordPress and it said that the Wordpress version was not the latest so I updated it to 5.4.2 (the server runs on PHP 5.6.40). For some reason now I'm not able to edit any of the pages this is the error message that I get:

> There was a serious error with our site. Check the mailbox for the administrator email address for details.

And I get this link: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

I'm not the administrator so I don't have access to those emails, however, I am the one who has to solve it.

I made a backup so if anything goes wrong I can restore the site.

So my questions are:

Is there a way to restore the version of WordPress to an older one if so should I?

Would it solve the problem if I updated the server's PHP to a newer version (7.3 possibly)?

Is there anyone who had a similar issue? How did you fix it?

Comment: You could try checking the error log if you have access to it, otherwise the only way to know what the actual problem is would be in those emails. Can you ask whoever has the address to give you the details? If not, you might need to restore the backup you have. For future reference, its always best to test an upgrade on a development version before updating the live site - plugins or theme code could stop working after upgrades especially if its a big jump in versions.

Comment: This nearly feels like a good question for [wordpress.se], no?

Answer (score 0):

You're running an older version of php. You can update it to 7.*...

From Wordpress website.

> To run WordPress we recommend your host supports:
> • PHP version 7.4 or greater.
> • MySQL version 5.6 or greater OR MariaDB version 10.1 or greater.
> • HTTPS support

Reference: https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

In addition I would suggest you deactivate all plugins and/or theme and try again, then troubleshoot by activating one at a time to see if there are is anything that are causing the error. Some themes/plugins will have a minimum system requirement to run.

If you have access to the wordpress logs they may assist you in your debugging.

Good luck!